# Setting DNS records and virtualhost

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualhost, apache-2.4, namecheap

My website currently lives on beta.tpe-edu.com
I want to make it accessible directly on tpe-edu.com (to point to the same location), but can't make it work (ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED).
Domain is registered via namecheap - DNS records (TLS 1 minute):

```
A record | IP Address: 52.28.32.146 | beta
A record | IP Address: 52.28.32.146 | www
A record | IP Address: 52.28.32.146 | @
```

Website is running on Amazon's EC2 (Debian).
Apache Virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName tpe-edu.com
   ServerAdmin admin@tpe-edu.com
   DocumentRoot /opt/tpe/public
   <Directory />
      Options +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log


</VirtualHost>
```

access via 'beta' or IP works fine
DNS records was changes about 48 hours ago.

Any ideas what I should check?

Comment: You do not have any aliases in your virtualhost for www and beta.

Comment: If it's his only configuration it will default to this vhost anyway.  You should stick to www. And 301 the root domain there

Comment: If it is his only one than he should not even need a virtualhost, than the default server would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is a glitch in Namecheap's administration.
DNS records which are set to OFF are still active (so it collides with other records).

Confirmed by their support.

Comment: Cheap, they got that right